How to implement a 24-hour time picker in Dash Plotly without regional time formatting?
I am trying to integrate a time picker in my Dash Plotly application. I have tried using an input with type='time', which works fine, but it picks the regional time format. The requirement is to allow the selection of time in a 24-hour format.
Here's a basic example of what I have tried:
import dash
from dash import dcc, html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Label('Select Time:'),
    dcc.Input(type='time', id='time-picker', value='12:00'),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

Issue:
The above code picks the time format based on regional settings (e.g., 12-hour AM/PM), but I need a 24-hour format consistently.
What I have tried:
Setting type='time' in dcc.Input.
Checked browser settings, which affect the display but not the requirement.
Requirement:
I need a time picker that allows selecting time in a 24-hour format without depending on the regional settings of the browser or the operating system.
Any suggestions or alternative components that could help achieve this in Dash Plotly?

A similar question has been asked and commented on in the plotly community. If it is a type of input, I think we can set a start and end time.

Note dcc.Input(type='time') is not officially supported by Dash, the allowed types are :  'text', 'number', 'password', 'email', 'range', 'search', 'tel', 'url' or 'hidden'; default 'text'). I suggest using TimeInput from Dash Mantine Components instead.

but everytime when my application loads it shows me 12 hours time format with AM and  PM. and my requirement it should be only 24 hours format. @EricLavault

You could build your own time picker in Plotly Dash with your desired format. Here is an simple example using the dcc.Dropdown components for input.


from dash import Dash, dcc, html

hours = [f"{i:0{2}}" for i in range(24)]
minutes = [f"{i:0{2}}" for i in range(60)]
seconds = [f"{i:0{2}}" for i in range(60)]

picker_style = {
    "display": "inline-block",
    "width": "40px",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "border": "none",
}

separator = html.Span(":")

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Label("Select Time:"),
        html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    hours,
                    placeholder="HH",
                    style=picker_style,
                ),
                separator,
                dcc.Dropdown(minutes, placeholder="MM",         style=picker_style),
                separator,
                dcc.Dropdown(seconds, placeholder="SS", style=picker_style),
            ],
            style={
                "border": "1px solid gray",
                "width": "140px",
                "display": "flex",
                "align-items": "center",
            },
        ),
    ],
    style={"font-family": "courier"},
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)


Thanks @nhorner this is a good solution it works
